# When installing Linux, what does remove all Linux partitions mean?

Tags: linux, partitioning, centos

The Linux installation screen offers me the option to remove all Linux partitions and to create a default layout however what does this mean exactly? Does it mean that if I have Fedora installed, it will delete Fedora and replace it with say CentOS? What if I have Windows installed and select the option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CentOS "Remove all linux partitions" means that it will leave intact any partitions containing filesystems that are not specifically for linux.  This would leave any NTFS, VFAT or FAT partitions.

This can be useful where you have a dual boot Windows / Linux system already, and want to do a clean install of linux without affecting Windows.

Comment: @Peanuts - actually, does it definitely say "Linux Partitions" rather than just partitions?  What distribution is this?

Comment: There is only one peanutsmonkey :-). Yes it offers me to options and based on your answer it is more confusing. The first option is to remove all partitions and create a default layout and the second option is to remove linux partitions and create a default layout. The distribution I am attempting to install is CentOS

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey Ok, in that case my answer was wrong and has been changed.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey - If you're a bit unsure or want a safe way to test things out, give VirtualBox or VMWare Player a try.

Comment: @Paul - Thanks. I suspected so. I take it that if I wanted to dual-boot say both Ubuntu and CentOS, I would choose the option use unused space on partition or possibly define a custom layout? Also did you change your answer because it varies from distribution to distribution?

Comment: @Joe Internet - Will definitely look into VirtualBox and VMWare but wanted to understand what it actually meant.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey Yes, you would choose unused or custom depening on how it was currently setup.  This option for removing only linux partitions seems to be a CentOS/RH thing, I haven't noticed it on other distributions.

Comment: @Paul - Righto. Thanks. Will play around with the options to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It means that it will remove all the Linux partition along with Windows partition. Advisable not to use if you want dual boot you system.
If you want to [install Linux](http://opensource-sidh.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-install-linux-operating-system.html) check out the proper method